# Covert groups to json after groupby() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert groups to dict after `groupby` function in pandas.
This is the data sample:

```
  user  val1   val2
0    A     1    one
1    A     3    one
2    A     2    one
3    B     2    two
4    B     2  three
5    C     3    one
```

After

```
df = df.groupby('user')
```

I want to get result something like this:

```
group_A = {'val1':[1,3,2], 'val2':['one', 'one', 'one']}
group_B = {'val1':[2,2], 'val2':['two', 'three']}
group_C = {'val1':[3], 'val2':['one']}
```

So for example:

```
for group in df:
    print(group)
```

Result:

```
{'val1':[1,3,2], 'val2':['one', 'one', 'one']}
{'val1':[2,2], 'val2':['two', 'three']}
{'val1':[3], 'val2':['one']}
```

Comment: This looks like a h=job for [Pandas to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), whayt have you tried and what went wrong with your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do

```
df.groupby('user').agg(lambda x : x.values.tolist()).to_dict('records')
Out[165]: 
[{'val1': [1, 3, 2], 'val2': ['one', 'one', 'one']},
 {'val1': [2, 2], 'val2': ['two', 'three']},
 {'val1': [3], 'val2': ['one']}]
```

Or

```
d = df.groupby('user').agg(lambda x : x.values.tolist()).to_dict('index')
d['A']
```

If do need for loop

```
for x, y in df.groupby('user'):
    print(y.drop(['user'],1).to_dict('list'))
```

Comment: how can I loop trough it? for group in d: print(group)

Comment: @taga check the update

Answer (score -2):

So, i came up with the same idea of Beny but with a function to store it in a variable :

```
group_A, group_B, group_C = {},{},{}

def add_to_dict (user_dict,user): 
  d = df.groupby('user').agg(lambda x : x.values.tolist()).to_dict('index')
  return (d[user])

group_A = add_to_dict(group_A,'A')
group_B = add_to_dict(group_B,'B')
group_C = add_to_dict(group_C,'C')
```